# Performing Sine inverse calculation in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I am trying to find the formula for sine inverse calculation using Safe software FME.

Is there any function in ExpressionEvaluator?.

Comment: in FME Workbench on the canvas type 'PolylineAnalyzer' it will be downloaded from the FME Store and you can use this to find angles in degrees for your line. It has many functions you will have to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse sine function, or arcsine can be performed in the ExpressionEvaluator by using `asin`.  Remember, the result will be in radians.

From the [**ExpressionEvaluator**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/expressionevaluator.htm) documentation:

> asin(arg)
>
> Returns the arc sine of arg, in the range [-pi/2,pi/2] radians. Arg should be in the range [-1,1].

Comment: Converting radians to degrees is a trivial exercise and you should be able to do it easily in expressionevalutator.

Comment: Please can provide sample sine angle calculation for 0.66 in FME expressionevalutator.

Comment: AngleConverter will convert radians into decimal degrees.

Comment: I suggest that comments which represent good answers are posted as such so that this one has a possibility of being registered as answered.